# httpd permissions while working

Tags: server, personal-website, httpd

I'm previewing my site as I work on it using httpd, but I had to move it into the `/var/www/html` directory.

Now I have to log in as root every time I want to modify a file, and it's difficult to use the GUI file manager (Nautilus on Fedora 16) to do anything.

What are some ways of making it easier to modify files while still begin able to preview them on a local server? Maybe this is more of a question about permissions on Linux...not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add all the files below /www/html to a user group of which your regular shell account is also a member of and that group has RW access to those files, this way you don't have to login as root to modify files.

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for.